# Installing PyAudio in Python Anywhere Bash console

Tags: python, flask, speech-recognition, pyaudio, pythonanywhere

I am using Python Anywhere to deploy a Flask web app. The app needs PyAudio to work. I am attempting to download PyAudio through the bash console (in a venv). When I run

```sh
pip install file:///C:/Users/usr/Downloads/PyAudio-0.2.11-cp38-cp38-win32.whl
```

it says

```sh
ERROR: PyAudio-0.2.11-cp38-cp38-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

Comment: Welcome Lucky!
It does not become clear what it is exactly what you are asking.
Can you describe it more closely? What kind of error is returned after executed your command?
What did you try to fix it?

Comment: I have edited my initial post for hopefully a better understanding. Sorry for the inconvenience. (And for the time delay)

Comment: The command 

    pip install file:///C:/Users/usr/Downloads/PyAudio-0.2.11-cp38-cp38-win32.whl

...would not work on PythonAnywhere, as the path you're providing is a Windows one and PythonAnywhere is a Linux environment.  It also looks like you're trying to install the Windows version of PyAudio.  

All that said, what does your site use PyAudio for?  Code running on PythonAnywhere runs on cloud servers, which don't have sound hardware, so you would not be able to record or play back audio on them.

Answer (score 1):

First, I would recommmend finding the virtualenv you created, then activating it, then installing the package.

1.
In pythonanywhere, the environment directory could be stored:

- in the project directory (if created like `python -m venv env`)
- in ~/.virtualenvs (if created like `mkvirtualenv my_app`, i.e. with virtualenvwrapper)

To check if its in ~/.virtualenvs, you can run `lsvirtualenv` in bash, and check if it's there.

2.
If it's in the project directory, just `source env/bin/activate` to activate it.  If it's been created via virtualenvwrapper (i.e. it's in ~/.virtualenvs), you can `workon my_app`.  Make sure to specify the correct name for the environment.

3.
Once activated, you can install the package just as you say: `pip install ...`

Hope this is the answer you were looking for!